# How can I set instance variables in classes that update constantly depending on the value of other instance variables?

Tags: java, instance-variables

I want to set an instance variable that relies on another.

I tried to define my new instance variable refering to another. For example:

```
public class numbers{
    int value;
    int triple=3*value;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I expected that whenever I updated the independent variable (in the example it would be `value`) through class methods, the variable `triple` would update along with the new value of `value`, but when I run the debugger the dependent variable stays at its default value.

Answer (score 1):

This line of code:

```
int triple=3*value;
```

... only gets executed once per object instantiation. At that point, `value` will be 0, therefore `triple` will also be 0 (= 3 * 0).

If you want something to appear to be constantly updated, use a getter method (it can be public or private depending on who needs to call it):

```
public class numbers{
    int value;

    private int getTripleValue() {
        return 3 * value;
    }
}
```

Then, each time you call `getTripleValue()`, the result will be calculated for `value` at that point in time, therefore always being 'up to date'.

**Pro tip:** Capitalise the first letter of your class names. It's a standard, and it makes it easier to tell classes apart from variable names.

Answer (score 1):

The assignment in `int triple = 3 * value;` is only done once, to the value evaluated at that time. There is no inherent binding between those two variables after that point.

A common pattern for hiding the internals of the fields is to use getters and setters, where you could make your class behave like you want. Depending on how exactly you want that triple to behave, you could either set its value on the setter for value:

```
public class Numbers{
    private int value;
    private int triple;
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.triple = 3 * value;
    }
    public int getTriple() {
        return triple;
    }
}
```

Or you could just get rid of the triple field completely, and just replace it with a method:

```
public class Numbers{
    private int value;

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public int getTriple() {
        return 3 * value;
    }
}
```

I left the setter for triple out for both cases, as its behavior would depend on what you want to do if the value is not divisible by three -- it seems like you want the value to be read-only anyway...